# How to modify the sender ViewController from the called ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a login view controller called from a Storyboard segue. When the user logs in correctly, I need to close the current ViewController, return to the caller ViewController and hide the login button.

How can I refer to the sender ViewController, to hide the button? Do I have to pass an instance of the `root` ViewController to the login or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delegation.

For your DetaliViewControler create a protocol, like

```
@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)successFullyLoggedInOnController:(DetailViewController *) controller;
@end
```

add a delegate declaration to DetailViewController's interface like

```
@property (weak) id<DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Make the MasterViewController conform to the protocol.

```
-(void)successFullyLoggedInOnController:(DetailViewController *) controller
{
    [self.loginButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

Now just before the MasterViewController displays the DetailViewController, doe something like

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailViewSegue"]) {
        DetailViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

In the DetailViewController once the credential where entered and verified call

```
[self.delegate successFullyLoggedInOnController:self];
```

and dismiss the DetailViewController

Answer (score 1):

You should use delegation. Make the VC with the button the other one's delegate. When log in is successful, you dismiss your VC and call the delegate method to hide the button.